Flet NavigationDrawer doesn't open, raises AssertionError: Control must be added to the page first
So, I'm trying to make a Flet app to give useful info to people in my town such as news, recycling, events,... Basically, I put the various categories in a NavigationDrawer, which is opened through a hamburger button placed on the appbar.
When I try to open it with page.open(drawer), it raises this error:
AssertionError: Control must be added to the page first.
This error usually happens when the page.drawer is not set, but that's not the case.
I tried debugging a bit and it turns out that, if I use page.drawer.open = True, the drawer opens succesfully, but it doesn't show.
Instead, with the first approach (described in the docs), it raises said error.
Code: (I replaced long parts with comments)
# Handle drawer navigation with page.go(<route corresponding to index>)

  drawer = ft.NavigationDrawer(
      on_change=handle_change,
      controls=[
          ft.Container(height=12),
          ft.NavigationDrawerDestination(
              label="Home",
              icon=ft.icons.HOME,
              selected_icon_content=ft.Icon(ft.icons.HOME_FILLED),
          ),
          ft.Divider(thickness=2),
          ft.NavigationDrawerDestination(
              icon_content=ft.Icon(ft.icons.NEWSPAPER),
              label="Notizie",
              selected_icon=ft.icons.NEWSPAPER_OUTLINED,
          ),
          ft.NavigationDrawerDestination(
              icon_content=ft.Icon(ft.icons.RECYCLING),
              label="Differenziata",
              selected_icon=ft.icons.RECYCLING_OUTLINED,
          )
      ]
  )

  
  def show_drawer(e):
      page.open(drawer)

  hamburger_btn = ft.IconButton(
      icon=ft.icons.MENU,
      on_click=show_drawer
  )

  page.drawer = drawer
  
  # Route change event handler

  def view_pop(view):
      page.views.pop()
      top_view = page.views[-1]
      page.go(top_view.route)

  page.on_route_change = route_change
  page.on_view_pop = view_pop
  # appbar creation with page.appbar
  page.update()
  page.go(page.route)



If you are following one of the tutorials for navigating via routes I believe you may have some code that looks like this:
def route_change(e: ft.RouteChangeEvent) -> None:
        page.views.clear() # <-- destroys the view each time it swaps. Navdrawer will not be assigned to the new view.
        page.views.append(
            ft.View(
            route ="/", 
            controls = [
                ft.Text(value="Home", size=30),
                ft.ElevatedButton(text='route2', on_click=lambda _: page.go('/route2')) 
            ])) # and any other navigation buttons for other routes

        match page.route:               
            case "/route2":
                page.views.append(
                    ft.View(
                        route= "/route2",
                        controls = [ft.Text("route2", size=30)],
                        vertical_alignment= ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                        horizontal_alignment= ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                        spacing = 26
                    )
                )
            
            case "/route3":
                page.views.append(
                    ft.View(
                        route= "/route3",
                        controls = [ft.Text("route3", size=30)],
                        vertical_alignment= ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                        horizontal_alignment= ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                        spacing = 26
                    )
                )

        print(page.views)
        page.views[-1].drawer = drawer # <-- Reassigns the drawer to the drawer attribute for the current view being displayed. 
        page.update()

A quick and dirty way is just add page.views[-1].drawer = nav_bar at the end of the route change function to reassign the drawer to the last view's drawer attribute. You could also do .end_drawer to get the navdrawer on the right. This seemed to fix the problem for me.
